# How to pass parameter in crosstab stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

This is my query:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`multicahaya`@`%` PROCEDURE `crosstonnercabang`(
IN in_cabang varchar(5)
)
BEGIN 
#SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SET group_concat_max_len = 8192;
#SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000000;
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT(
'max(case when tonner = ''',
tonner,
''' then vol_sub else 0 end) AS ',
tonner
)
) INTO @sql
FROM t1pkbtm_;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT bln_pkb,cabang,warna,gol,pkb, ', @sql, ', sum(vol_sub) as `count`
FROM t1pkbtm_ where cabang=',in_cabang,' 
GROUP BY pkb ORDER BY bln_pkb,pkb,warna');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

But it is showing error:

1054 - Unknown column 'bt' in 'where clause' ---- crosstonnercabang('bt')

I don't know how to pass parameters in Pivot Query.

Comment: Withoiut tables data and your procedure call it is impossible to say anything. make a call proceure and then make a SELECT @sql;  and check what the result is.

Comment: You should also use [QUOTE(tonner)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_quote) when you concatenate it into your query, in case tonner contains some special characters.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a placeholder in the query for a parameter. This is safer because it protects against SQL injection. Putting extra quotes around the variable when concatenating will not work if the value contains quotes.

```
@cabang = in_cabang;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT bln_pkb,cabang,warna,gol,pkb, ', @sql, ', sum(vol_sub) as `count`
FROM t1pkbtm_ where cabang= ? 
GROUP BY pkb ORDER BY bln_pkb,pkb,warna');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt USING @cabang;
```

Note that the variables used in `EXECUTE stmt USING` must be session variables, so you need to assign `in_cabang` to `@cabang`.

Comment: thank you, is it possible to use many parameters likr ex: EXECUTE stmt USING in_cabang,in_month1,in_month2

Comment: Yes, the `?` are replaced in order.

Comment: the correct answer just put \ like cabang=\'',in_cabang,'\'

Comment: and I add where cabang=\'',in_cabang,'\' and bln_pkb BETWEEN \'',in_month1,'\' AND \'',in_month2,'\' 
is it same for numeric using \'

Comment: You don't need quotes around numbers.

Comment: I've updated the answer. The parameters in `USING` have to be `@` variables. Doing it this way protects against SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Here the correct answer:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `crosstonnercabang`(
IN in_cabang varchar(5)
)
BEGIN 
#SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SET group_concat_max_len = 8192;
#SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000000;
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT(
'max(case when tonner = ''',
tonner,
''' then vol_sub else 0 end) AS ',
tonner
)
) INTO @sql
FROM t1pkbtm_;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT bln_pkb,cabang,warna,gol,pkb, ', @sql, ', sum(vol_sub) as `count`
FROM t1pkbtm_ where cabang=\'',in_cabang,'\' 
GROUP BY pkb ORDER BY bln_pkb,pkb,warna');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;


END
```